# Compress files and directories

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, tar

I need to compress certain files and a directory. Suppose they're placed in /root/project.
The thing is that i need to compress them in a gzip-tarball format with certain name (name.tar.gz) and in the "root" directory, i mean, that as soon as i opened the .tar.gz all the files and directories i want to compress are there.

I have tried using the following commands:

```
tar czfv name.tar.gz /root/project
tar czfv name.tar.gz /root/project/*
```

but then the whole substructure gets compress (i mean, when i open the .tar.gz i have to navigate through the directories root/project.. which i dont, i need that the files were as soon as i opened in "/" i suppose)

I hope i've explained myself... excuse me for my bad english and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU tar you can use the following command:

`tar -C /root/project -zcvf /root/name.tar.gz .`

The `-C` causes tar to change to the `/root/project` directory before adding the `.` directory to the archive.  Make sure the destination directory for your archive is not in the directory you are archiving (/root/project).  This example creates the archive in /root.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the filenames in the tarball to all have a `project/` prefix (which is often advisable), do

```
(cd /root && tar czvf `pwd`/name.tar.gz project)
```

If you don't want a prefix at all, do

```
(cd /root/project && tar czvf `pwd`/name.tar.gz .)
```

(The `pwd` captures the present working directory prior to doing the `cd`; the parentheses execute the command in a subshell so your current shell stays in the same directory.)

Comment: The second choice is what i want! Thank you! Only problem is that when i compress, the .tar.gz gets compress along the other files too! (kind of a recursive thing :S)

Comment: @Lucia: I don't know what you mean. The `z` option to `tar` causes the entire file to be compressed.

Comment: When i open the newly name.tar.gz file, inside it appear along with all the files compressed another name.tar.gz with 0Bytes.. :S i dont know why.

Comment: Probably because you accidentally created that file in the directory with a previous attempt to tar it.

Comment: hehe, i think that too.. but i delete the file and tried again and nothing... :(